# Get value of selected div and carry to the next page with php

Tags: php

I've trying to set up a multiple page donation form. I've got it set up where a user can select from a few different boxes that all have different amounts of money in them. What I want is for it to carry the value of the selected box to the next page via a php session variable. I have an input box that that actually enter text into that I figured out just fine but I just can't figure out how to get the value of the boxes. Thanks.

```
<form role="form" action="donation.php">
    <div class="donate-box col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2">
        <div class="donate-amounts">
        <ul id="amounts">
        <a href="#"><li>$15</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>$25</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>$50</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>$100</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>$200</li></a>
        </ul>
        </div><!-- End donate amounts -->
        <div class="donate-other">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="otheramount">Other</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="otheramount" placeholder="$" name="otheramount">
            </div>
        </div><!-- End donate other -->
        <div class="donate-month">
            <label for="monthly">Monthly</label>
            <div id="donate-month-check" class="donate-checkbox check-blank">
            <div id="month-check-on" style="display: none;"><img src="img/check.png"></div>
            </div>


        </div><!-- End donate month -->

        <div class="donate-one-time">
            <label for="one">One Time</label>
            <div id="donate-one-check" class="donate-checkbox check-blank">
            <div id="one-check-on" style="display: none;"><img src="img/check.png"></div>
            </div>                      
        </div><!-- End donate one time -->


        <div class="donate-submit">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default donate-button">Donate Now</button>
        </div>

    </form>


$(function money () {
        $('li').click(function () {
            $('#amounts li').removeClass('clicked');
            $('.donate-other').removeClass('clicked');
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
        });

        $('.donate-other').click(function () {
            $('#amounts li').removeClass('clicked');
            $(this).addClass('clicked');
        });

        $('#donate-month-check').click(function () {
            $('#one-check-on').hide();
            $('#month-check-on').toggle();
        });

         $('#donate-one-check').click(function () {
            $('#month-check-on').hide();
            $('#one-check-on').toggle();
        });

        $('#amounts li').click(function() { 
            $('#otheramount').val('0');

        })

    });
```

Comment: You can use javascript to get the values. Why dont you use a select box or radio buttons?

Comment: Firstly, your a tags belong inside your li tags. Second what you want to do is easy in javascript...are you familiar with javascript?

Comment: Why use javascript here? Keep things simple: just make html links and all is fine: `<li><a href="yourscript.php?amount=15">€15</a></li>` Remember: the OP asked about "the next page", so a full reload.

Comment: I am somewhat familiar with javascript. The hard part for me is that after they select a box they then have to select a check box then submit. I would just pass the data in the href but i don't want them to go until they hit submit.

Comment: We need to see all your code

Comment: Ok, I added the whole form and the jquery that it uses. Basically I want to pass the selected dollar amount and the checked box to the next page upon submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? Here is the fiddle that I created: http://jsfiddle.net/56BCe/

```
    $('#amounts li').click(function() { 
        $('#otheramount').val($(this).text());
    })
```

Comment: @jlemm45 is this answer correct? If so can you check it as the answer? Or any of the others if they are the correct answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="donate-amounts">
    <ul id="amounts">   
    <a href="your_url?amount=15"><li>$15</li></a>
```

your_url.php

```
($_GET["amount"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the data by a GET Request:

```
<div class="donate-amounts">
    <ul id="amounts">
        <a href="page.php?quantity=15"><li>$15</li></a>
        <a href="page.php?quantity=25"><li>$25</li></a>
        <a href="page.php?quantity=50"><li>$50</li></a>
        <a href="page.php?quantity=100"><li>$100</li></a>
        <a href="page.php?quantity=200"><li>$200</li></a>
    </ul>
```

and then in the page.php get the quantity variable:

```
<?
$quantity = $_GET['quantity'];
?>
```